# Upper bound for a ratio of modified Bessel functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, analytic-number-theory, special-functions

I am looking for an upper bound for the ratio of Bessel I functions $\dfrac{|I_\nu'(z)|}{|I_\nu(z)|}$ where $\nu$ is complex, and $z$ is a positive real number. Do you know any results about it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For positive $\nu$, this reference gives an answer: arxiv.org/pdf/1009.4814.pdf . If $\nu$ is not restricted to be positive, there may be zeros of $I_\nu$ on the positive real axis, so we cannot expect an upper bound unless we know the location of these zeros.